# how to check multiple characters in a string more efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, in:

`str = "aaa111bbb222ccc333ddd444eee555fff666"`

i want to check if the characters that should be letters, are letters. I could do:

`if str[0:3].isalpha() and str[6:9].isalpha() and str[12:15].isalpha() and str[18:21]` et cetera

but with my actual code that would be way too long of an if statement, i would like to use only one ".isalpha()" and check all the characters at once

Comment: So why not `str[0:3].isalpha() and str[6:9].isalpha()`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i have many more characters in my code, that was just an example

Comment: I don't understand. You "want to check if the first 3 characters and the 7th to 9th characters are letters". This is precisely what this line does. What is the problem with it? Show an example where this is not working as intended.

Comment: okay i fixed the question, i wrongly said "with one line" instead of "more efficiently"

Comment: "but with my actual code" — Perhaps you could give an example that represents your actual code so people can see the actual problem they are being asked.

Comment: @khelwood how about now?

Comment: Still doesn't look "too long" to me.

Comment: How many substrings are you actually checking? And are they always three characters long and sre the starting indexes the multiples of 6?

Comment: @don't talk just code nope, there's no "logical" order and they could be 1-3 characters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this function help you??

```
str = "aaa111bbb222ccc333ddd444eee555fff666"

def my_is_alpha(string, list):
    for start, end in list:
        if not string[start:end].isalpha():
            return False
    return True

list = [(0, 3), (6, 9), (12, 15)]
print(my_is_alpha(str, list))
```

**Output:**

```
> True
```

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to your problem is a solution space called "Pattern matching." This particular kind of pattern matching appears to be a regular expression.

Though you haven't specified what your pattern is supposed to be, given your input I will assume that a matching string will be something like "Three letters, followed by three numbers, repeated an arbitrary number of times." That regular expression is:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r'''
(?:                            # open the group so we can repeat it later
  \w{3}                        # three letters
  \d{3}                        # three numbers
)+                             # repeated one or more times
''', re.X)
```

You can then check a string against this pattern with `re.match`

```py
s = 'aaa111bbb222ccc333ddd444eee555fff666'
assert re.match(pat, s)

s2 = 'arbitrary non-matching string'
assert not re.match(pat, s2)
```

Comment: They said there's no "logical" order and they could be 1-3 characters long

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode the order cannot _actually_ be arbitrary since the premise of the question is that there is a "correct" pattern. OP is just failing to express it. I'm hoping that this answer will lead them along the right path to expressing the real pattern they're trying to verify.

Comment: @AdamSmith unfurtunately this isn't the answer i was looking for when i asked this, i'll try again with a better question after the cooldown period, and after i've formed a better question

Comment: @Tommy good luck! You should try formulating the question for yourself, first! What does a "valid input" look like. How does it differ from an invalid input? Regular expressions are almost certainly what you need, but unless you can express what the pattern is that you're matching against it's tough to answer.